# change property dynamically while serializing generic class

Tags: android, realm, gson

I have following generalized class that i am trying to serialize using the Gson library.

```
public class TRequest<T> implements RealmModel {


    private RealmList<T> requestList;

    public RealmList<T> getRequestList() {
        return requestList;
    }

    public void setRequestList(RealmList<T> requestList) {
        this.requestList = requestList;
    }
}
```

Have written following code to serialize data

```
    //crate fitness object
    Fitness fitness = new Fitness();
    fitness.set_id("100");
    fitness.setIntensity("2300");

    //create realm list
    RealmList<Fitness> fitnessRealmList  = new RealmList<Fitness>();
    fitnessRealmList.add(fitness);

    //create tRequest object
    TRequest<Fitness> tRequest = new TRequest<Fitness>();
    tRequest.setRequestList(fitnessRealmList);


    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = builder.create();


    //serialize it 
    String stringData = gson.toJson(tRequest);
```

As a result i am getting following output

> {"requestList":[{"_id":"100","intensity":"2300"}]}

as my class is generic i want to change the property value dynamic from "requestList" to "fitness". likewise if i am serializing routine object then it should replace "requestList" to "routine".

expected output is

> {"fitness":[{"_id":"100","intensity":"2300"}]}

i tried type token as follows , but it did not work

```
    Type type  = new  TypeToken<Fitness>(){}.getType();
    String stringData = gson.toJson(tRequest,type);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try a custom serializer as explained here: [link](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Writing-a-Serializer)

Here is an example:

```
public class TRequest<T> {

    private final String attributeName;
    private RealmList<T> requestList;

    public TRequest(String attributeName) {
        this.attributeName = attributeName;
    }

    public String getAttributeName() {
        return attributeName;
    }

    public RealmList<T> getRequestList() {
        return requestList;
    }

    public void setRequestList(RealmList<T> requestList) {
        this.requestList = requestList;
    }
}

public class MySerializer implements JsonSerializer<TRequest<?>> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(TRequest<?> t, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsc) {
        JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
        obj.add(t.getAttributeName(), jsc.serialize(t.getRequestList()));
        return obj;
    }

}

//when using it
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(TRequest.class, new MySerializer());
Gson gson = builder.create();
String toJson = gson.toJson(tRequest);
```

Comment: your answer is too generalize

Comment: Problem with this approach is we are creating new jsonObject hence other fields in `Request` class got vanished

Comment: you have to add all fields you want to serialize in `MySerializer`'s `serialize` method

Comment: Does it going degrade the performance related to serializing ?

Comment: i don't think so, it can be faster i think, because there is less reflection needed to get field-info (which to serialize, which not, etc)

Comment: well there are around 10 to 15 fields in a class so i think need to find some other way